# TableView didSelectRowAt no funciona

Tags: swift, xcode

estoy siguiendo un curso de programación en swift, voy en la parte de crear tablas y darle eventos a los row que seleccione el usuario al dar clic, mi error es que ya tengo la vista completa, todo funciona bien el delegate y el datasource están bien la tabla me muestra la lista de los archivos que quiero mostrar, el problema persiste en al darle clic en cualquier row no hace nada la primera vez, cuando ya selecciono otro row ahora si me carga el row anterior seleccionado y al dar clic a un tercero me selecciona el row anterior, es decir, siempre me selecciona el ultimo que fue clickeado por el usuario el código es el siguiente:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

var contenidoCeldas = ["pdf1","pdf2","pdf3"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return contenidoCeldas.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let celda = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    celda.textLabel?.text=contenidoCeldas[indexPath.row]
    return celda
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let idPDFSeleccionado = indexPath.row
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "PantallaDosSegue", sender: idPDFSeleccionado)
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if(segue.identifier=="PantallaDosSegue"){
                print("entro aqui")
                let idPdfSeleccionadoRecibido = sender as! Int
                let objPantalla2:ViewControllerPantalla2 = segue.destination as! ViewControllerPantalla2
        objPantalla2.nombrepdfRecibido = contenidoCeldas[idPdfSeleccionadoRecibido]

    }
}
```

Realmente no se que tengo mal espero que me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia el código:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let idPDFSeleccionado = indexPath.row
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "PantallaDosSegue", sender: idPDFSeleccionado)
}
```

Por este:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: Indexpath){let idPDFSeleccionado = indexPath.row
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "PantallaDosSegue", sender: idPDFSeleccionado)
}
```

El que pones es la función del delgado para cuando se deselecciona una celda no cuando selecciona el que puse es **didSelect** diferente al **DidDeselect**